# ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions, ruby-on-rails-5, rollback

I am doing a simple project which has four model Owner Store Product Warehouse

Owner

```
class Owner < ApplicationRecord
has_one :store
end
```

Store

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  
  has_many :ware_houses
  has_many :products, through: :ware_houses
end
```

Product

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  

  has_many :ware_houses
  has_many :stores, through: :ware_houses

end
```

WareHouse

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :ware_houses
  has_many :stores, through: :ware_houses

end
```

first I add o1 as Owner by

```
 o1 = Owner.new(name: "o1") then save it
```

then add s1 as store by `s1 = Store.new(name: "s1")`
assign s1 to o1 by writing

```
o1.store = s1
```

I tried to add three product by using `p1 = Product.new(name: "p1")`

but When I wanted to assign **p1,p2,p3 to s1** by `s1.products = [p1, p2]`
it will show this

```
Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "ware_houses" ON "products"."id" = "ware_houses"."product_id" WHERE "ware_houses"."store_id" = ?  [["store_id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Product Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "P1"], ["created_at", "2020-06-23 17:35:41.028631"], ["updated_at", "2020-06-23 17:35:41.028631"]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):16
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: products.store_id)
```

was following a tutorial online, 
 not quite sure about this unfinished process..
it seems like p1,p2 is not successfully assign to s1.

quite confused, would like to know how to fix it..
thanks a lot!

Comment: can you also post the timings of saving those objects (s1, p1, p2)?

Comment: Your schema does not match your application code. The schema is consistent with product belonging to a store. Fix migrations if necessary to match the models, then drop the database and remigrate.

Comment: @Fernand I wrote s1.products = [p1, p2] after I ran p1 = Product.new( name: "p1") and p2 = Product.new(name: "p2")

Comment: @D.SM is that right I remove line [ t.references :store, null: false, foreign_key: true in db/migrate/XXXX_create_products.rb ]  then do $ rake db:drop db:create db:migrate ? thank you

Comment: That should work if your code and migrations are consistent.

Comment: @D.SM  appreciate your help, finally get it right! :)